# jQuery remove first two specific items from total price

Tags: jquery, input, each

In my application people can order products in the way of fill down an input field next to the product with the amount they want.

In the same list there is also a specific section with 'testers' when customers order products, let's say 6 pieces, they can have 1 tester for free. People are able to buy more testers but the pay them.

I am struggling with the follow piece of code. What I need to do is to check the 'tester' input if they have a value, this is not the problem. Things getting more complicated if we have like 4 tester inputs with a value. Let's say the customer can order 2 free testers and the first and second input have an value of '1' (amount) and the third has '2'.. I only want to get the first two 'products' to exclude them from the total price.
The amount of 2 testers is variable.

```
<table>
<tr><td><input min="0"type="number"data-price="16.50" size="1" id="retail" value="" placeholder="0" name="583"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input min="0"type="number"data-price="16.50" size="1" id="tester" value="" placeholder="0" name="584"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input min="0"type="number"data-price="8.50" size="1" id="tester" value="" placeholder="0" name="585"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input min="0"type="number"data-price="4.50" size="1" id="tester" value="" placeholder="0" name="586"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input min="0"type="number"data-price="8.50" size="1" id="tester" value="" placeholder="0" name="587"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input min="0"type="number"data-price="2.50" size="1" id="tester" value="" placeholder="0" name="588"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Code:

```
      // has the value of the total free test products a customer can buy
      totalFreeTestProducts = (Math.floor(counter))


      $("table tr td input").each(function(index) {

      // product price
      price = $(this).data('price');

           // id is category
           if ($(this).attr('id') == 'testers') {

              // amount value is not 0
               if ($(this).val() > 0) {

                // Do something, sum the products based on
                // the amount of free testers to buy.

                }
           }

       });
```

Comment: I would need more info. I don't fully understand your problem and how to solve it, because of the lack of HTML code and/or better accuracy in your question.

Comment: I've updated with some example html code. When people buy like 24 pieces of a retail product. 'totalFreeTestProducts' var will contain '2' which means, they are able to get 2 testers for 'free'. They van buy 4 testers but, this should be minus the 2, so just 2 are left.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ID `tester` multiple times, you should use class on elements & then check if particular class exists on element using,

```
$(this).hasClass('tester'); // tester is class name
```

> Always remember that ID should be unique.

Comment: I know and you are right. But this is not the case for now I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like this that you are needing ?

```
var retailPrice = 0;
var testerPrice =0;

$("input").on("change", function () {
    var sum = 0;
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'retail') {

            var qty = $(this).val();
            if (qty == (6 * Math.floor(qty / 6))) {
                var freeTesterQty = $("#testerFree").val();
                if (freeTesterQty === "") {
                   freeTesterQty = parseInt(0);
                }

                freeTesterQty = (6 * Math.floor(qty / 6))/6;
                $("#testerFree").val(freeTesterQty);


            }else{

                freeTesterQty = (6 * Math.floor(qty / 6))/6;
                if(freeTesterQty == 0){
                    freeTesterQty="";
                }
                $("#testerFree").val(freeTesterQty);
            }
            retailPrice = $(this).attr('data-price') * qty;
            //sum += retailPrice;

        } else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'tester') {
            var qty = $(this).val();
            var freeTesterQty = $("#testerFree").val();
            if (freeTesterQty === "") {
               freeTesterQty = parseInt(0);
            }
            testerPrice = $(this).attr('data-price') * qty;
            //sum += testerPrice;

        }
    sum = retailPrice+testerPrice;
    $(".sum").html(sum + "€")
});
```

In this exemple, free tester appear each 6 products.

> [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b8u4xrbf/)

---

Update 1:

For more than one products inputs :

> [Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b8u4xrbf/4/)

---

Update 2:

Here is the JS code for more than one products/testers inputs :

```
var retailPrice = 0;
var testerPrice = 0;

$("input").on("change", function () {
    var sum = 0;
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'retail') {



            retailPrice = 0;
            var qty = 0;
            $(".retail").each(function(){
                var currRetailQty = $(this).val();
                if(currRetailQty == ""){
                    currRetailQty = 0;
                }
                qty += parseInt(currRetailQty);
                retailPrice += $(this).attr('data-price') * currRetailQty;

            });

            if (qty == (6 * Math.floor(qty / 6))) {
                var freeTesterQty = $("#testerFree").val();
                if (freeTesterQty === "") {
                   freeTesterQty = parseInt(0);
                }

                freeTesterQty = (6 * Math.floor(qty / 6))/6;
                $("#testerFree").val(freeTesterQty);


            }else{

                freeTesterQty = (6 * Math.floor(qty / 6))/6;
                if(freeTesterQty == 0){
                    freeTesterQty="";
                }
                $("#testerFree").val(freeTesterQty);
            }


        } else if ($(this).attr('class') == 'tester') {

            testerPrice = 0;
            var qty = 0;

            $(".tester").each(function(){
                var currClassQty = $(this).val();
                if(currClassQty == ""){
                    currClassQty = 0;
                }
                qty += parseInt(currClassQty);
                testerPrice += $(this).attr('data-price') * currClassQty;

            });


            /*var qty = $(this).val();
            var freeTesterQty = $("#testerFree").val();
            if (freeTesterQty === "") {
               freeTesterQty = parseInt(0);
            }
            testerPrice = $(this).attr('data-price') * qty;*/


        }
    sum = retailPrice+testerPrice;
    $(".sum").html(sum + "€")
});
```

> [Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8bwrpxsn/)

Comment: Thank you! the offered free testers are good, the amount of 'freeTesterQty' should not be included in the end price.

Comment: p.s. It's possible there are more test products in the list, this makes it complexer in the calculation

Comment: `freeTesterQty` isn't included in the end price, you can do a manual sum to see that : for 5 products, price is 82.5€ (5*16.50), and for 6 products, and 1 free tester, price is 99€ (6*16.50).

Comment: See "update 1" in my answer for more products solution

Comment: I am sorry, I updated the jsfiddler to give a better impression. https://jsfiddle.net/b8u4xrbf/6/ there is not just one test product to choose from.

Comment: Almost! Now just the only thing needs to be done is to exclude the 'free' chosen products from the end price.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74253/discussion-between-edensource-and-freshtea).